# How to combine two types in scala into single type definition

Tags: scala, types, mixins

This shows exactly what I'm trying to do:

```
type MyType = Value with MyTypeOperations
```

but this doesn't compile. Is there an other way do mix 2 types into one?

Comment: Is `MyTypeOperations` a trait?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
scala> class Value
defined class Value

scala> trait MyTypeOperations
defined trait MyTypeOperations

scala> type MyType = Value with MyTypeOperations
defined type alias MyType
```

Shows exactly how you can exactly do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't know why I was so sure it's a compiler error, you're absolutely right it compiles. I can't reconstruct the error I've been given. Thanks